# How do I make an Object's Compact Layout update when I make changes to it or assign it a new Compact Layout?

Tags: compact-layout

Even if I delete a Compact Layout, the Object (which is Account) will still have the now deleted Compact Layout showing when I open an Account record page. The Compact Layout updates and shows correctly on the Lightning Builder, but does not show correctly on the actual record.